# Add Windows 10 language pack via PowerShell

Tags: powershell, windows-10, language-packs

I'm trying to add a language pack to existing Windows 10 builds (mostly 20H2) but the language is only available and not downloaded as per the screenshot:

[image]

Only the default en-us can be selected as the Windows Display Language until en-IE is downloaded. Any PowerShell commands I find only work after the pack is downloaded. From what I've found the pack will only download manually after the system (WinHTTP) proxy is set.

Because en-IE is not an 'Experience Pack' it is not possible to add via DISM.

Comment: Hi, good question, I didnt find the way on my side, but just an workaround for until you find; if it's to distribute to multiple new PCs, I would suggest to pre-download it and sysprep after your image to re-image the pc.

Comment: Thanks, it's something I suggested but there is some compatibility issues with the latest build of Win 10 and our apps.

Comment: Looks like it's possible in Win 11 but not in Win 10 - https://www.itechtics.com/add-language-using-powershell/